# Call a method from console menu for a class that inherits the method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I've stumbled into an issue and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'll be adding a lot of code here, most of which probably won't be needed to answer my question.

I have a class called Employee, it's just a class for an Employee type object:

```java
class Employee extends ObjectIDs implements Output {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private static final String VALID_EMPLOYEE_NAME = "^[a-zA-Z]{2,50}$";

    Employee(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) throws Exception {
        super(id);
        this.setNames(firstName, lastName);
    }

    private void setNames(String firstName, String lastName) throws Exception {
        if ( !firstName.matches(VALID_EMPLOYEE_NAME) || !lastName.matches(VALID_EMPLOYEE_NAME)) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException (Store.ERR_PREFIX+"Please use english letters only ");
        }
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    String getNames () {
        return this.firstName+" "+lastName;
    }

    public String createOutput() {
        return this.id+","+this.firstName+","+this.lastName;    
    }
}
```

I have a Store class that inside of of it I'm creating an Employee list and a bunch of other things. All the methods for all of the other classes go there. For example, the method `newEmployee` and `removeEmployee` are in there, accessing the list I mentioned, etc. It will also include other methods for classes like `Product` but that's just an example. This is the `Store` class:

```java
class Store {

    private ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    static final String EMPLOYEES_FILE_PATH = "employees.csv";
    static final String PRODUCTS_FILE_PATH = "items.csv";
    static final String EMPLOYEES_LIST = "employees";
    static final String PRODUCT_LIST = "prodcuts";
    static final String ERR_PREFIX = "*********\nERROR\n*********\n";

    Employee newEmployee(Integer id ,String firstName, String lastName) throws Exception { //Create a new employee
        for ( Employee e : employees ) {
            if (id == e.id) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(ERR_PREFIX + "This employee ID already exist.");
            }
        }
        Employee e = new Employee(id, firstName, lastName);
        this.employees.add(e);
        System.out.println("Employee "+e.createOutput()+" added to the employees list");
        return e;
    }

    void deleteEmployee(Integer id) throws Exception { //Remove Employee
        for(int i = 0; i<employees.size(); i++) {
            if(employees.get(i).id == id) {
                System.out.println("Employee "+employees.get(i).createOutput()+" was deleted sucsessfully.");
                employees.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry, no such employee.");
    }
}
```

I have another class where I'm creating the menu. It's basically a menu that calls a submenu and from there I want to execute methods.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu = menu.mainMenu(menu);
        System.out.println("Thanks for visiting");
    }

    private Menu mainMenu(Menu menu) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to my store");
        int selection = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("[1] I'm a customer");
            System.out.println("[2] I'm an employee");
            System.out.println("[3] Quit");

            System.out.print("Insert selection: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            selection = sc.nextInt();

            switch (selection) {
            case 1: return menu.customerSubMenu(menu);
            case 2: return menu.employeeSubMenu(menu);
            case 3: return menu;
            default:
                System.out.println("The selection was invalid!");
            }
        } while (selection != 3);
        return menu;
    }

    private Menu customerSubMenu(Menu menu) { //Customer options submenu
        System.out.println("Welcome dear customer");

        int selection = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("[1] Register as new customer");
            System.out.println("[2] Buy an item");
            System.out.println("[3] Return");

            System.out.print("Insert selection: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            //selection = ++testint
            selection = sc.nextInt();

            switch (selection) {
            // case 1: return 
            // case 2: return 
            // case 3:
            default:
                System.out.println("The selection was invalid!");
        }
    } while (selection != 3);
    return menu;
}

private Menu employeeSubMenu(Menu menu) { //Employees options submenu
    System.out.println("Welcome employee");

    int selection = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("[1] Add a product");
        System.out.println("[2] Return a product");
        System.out.println("[3] Add an employee");
        System.out.println("[4] Show all employees");
        System.out.println("[5] Return");

        System.out.print("Insert selection: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // selection = ++testint;
        selection = sc.nextInt();

        switch (selection) {
            // case 1: return
            // case 2: return
            // case 3: return
            case 5:
                return menu.mainMenu(menu);
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid selection");
            }
        } while (selection != 5);
        return menu;
    }
}
```

If you scroll down to the `employeeSubMenu`, you'll see the I commented out `case 3` which I want to use to run the `newEmployee` method which is inside the `Store` class. Problem is, I'm doing something wrong. It won't let me do that and I can't call it by using `Store.newEmployee` nor by it's direct name. The question is why.

I'd love to get some help.

Please assume I'm very new to Java in your answers if possible as I'm honestly just learning.

Comment: This is because newEmployee method is not static. So in order to call it you must call it using an instance of Store class

Comment: @Shubham so I need to create a new employee inside the menu? Like `Employee e = new Employee()`? Because I already created one inside the `Store` class and I'm wondering why I can't see it.

Comment: Your newEmployee method is already creating an Employee. All you need to do is create Store object as Store st = new Store(); Then something like st.newEmployee(1,"First","Second");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `Store` class to use `static` methods and call from the cases in the switch using `Store.newEmployee(....)`

```
class Store {

        private static ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        private static ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        private static final String EMPLOYEES_FILE_PATH = "employees.csv";
        private  static final String PRODUCTS_FILE_PATH = "items.csv";
        private  static final String EMPLOYEES_LIST = "employees";
        private  static final String PRODUCT_LIST = "prodcuts";
        private  static final String ERR_PREFIX = "*********\nERROR\n*********\n";

       public static Employee newEmployee(Integer id ,String firstName, String lastName) throws Exception { //Create a new employee
            for ( Employee e : employees ) {
                if (id == e.id) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(ERR_PREFIX + "This employee ID already exist.");
                }
            }
            Employee e = new Employee(id, firstName, lastName);
            this.employees.add(e);
            System.out.println("Employee "+e.createOutput()+" added to the employees list");
            return e;
        }

        public static void deleteEmployee(Integer id) throws Exception { //Remove Employee
            for(int i = 0; i<employees.size(); i++) {
                if(employees.get(i).id == id) {
                    System.out.println("Employee "+employees.get(i).createOutput()+" was deleted sucsessfully.");
                    employees.remove(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry, no such employee.");
        }
    }
```

, or create `Store` object in menu and mark it as static and call it

```
private static Store store = new Store();

....
case 1: store.newEmployee(....);
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I only need to find a way to implement my file reader to take the arguments from a csv file. I hope I won't ask another question :)

Comment: where are these arguments? do you mean `EMPLOYEES_FILE_PATH`, etc variables in-store class?